# JQuery Mobile + ChartJS : Responsive Bar Chart displayed only after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, charts

I've been trying to add a responsive bar chart with Chart.js to one of my JQM projects.

This is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/mauriciorcruz/1pajh3zb/3/

Chart must be displayed on Page Two and it must be responsive. In my example, if you change `responsive : true` to **`false`**, it will work like a charm.

If `responsive` is set to `true`, after clicking the button you'll see nothing, but if you resize the screen the Chart will magically appear.

Any guesses why this is happening? I've tried different JQM events for `#pagetwo` without success.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you need to use [`pagecontainershow`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) event, when page is visible and all elements within have received dimensions http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/88Lubgsu/

Comment: Omar is correct. If you don't want to redraw the chart on subsequent visits, you can check if the chart has been created: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1pajh3zb/5/

Comment: Thanks @Omar, it works. I've seen that's a brand new event for JQM 1.4 . Any guesses how to solve my issue for previous JQM versions? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ezanker, I'll keep that in mind for my project.

Comment: for 1.3 use `pageshow`.

Comment: @ezanker post an answer, get some rep ;)

Comment: @Omar, thanks for passing some rep my way! I am almost at 10k now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQM 1.4, you would use the new pagecontainer widget's **[show](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show)** event to make sure the page is drawn and all dimensions are available for the responsive chart to calculate its width:

```
$( "body" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "pagetwo"){
        //show chart code here
    }
});
```

You use the ui parameter to see which page is being shown (`ui.toPage`).

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1pajh3zb/6/)**

For jQM 1.3, there was no pagecontainer, so you just use the `pageshow` event delegated to yoyr chart page:

```
$(document).on( "pageshow", "#pagetwo", function() {
    //show chart code here
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1pajh3zb/7/)**

Using the show event, you are now drawing the chart each time the page is shown. If the chart does not change between visits to the page, you could keep a global javascript variable for the chart once drawn and check if it needs to be drawn on each visit:

```
var barChart;
$(document).on( "pageshow", "#pagetwo", function() {
    if (barChart == null){
       //draw if barchart is null 

       window.barChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data...
    }
});
```

Comment: you're 10k now, enjoy ;)